# Thread synchronization with multiple methods

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a static class with multiple static methods.

```
private static Session _session = new Session();

public static void Method1() {
    if(_session != null)
        _session.Action();
}
public static void Method2() {
    if(_session != null)
        _session.Action();
}
public static void Method3() {
    if(_session != null)
        _session.Action();
}
public static void Method4(string path) {
    _session.Disconnect();
    _session.Connect(new Config(path));
}
```

Method1, Method2, Method3 are fully thread safe, they can be safely called simultaneously from any number of threads. In fact, for performance reasons, I need to allow multiple threads to call Method1,2,3 concurrently.

The problem is, it is possible for Method1,2,3 to throw an exception when Method4() is being called.
How do I allow multiple threads to call Method1,2,3 while also blocking them when Method4() is being called?

Comment: It sounds like you need a ReaderWriterLock.

Comment: Why are you setting the session to null?  Why not just set the session directly to a new session?

Comment: Servy - I might have oversimplified my example, but Method4() is basically: session.Disconnect() and session.Connect(newConfig). While this is happening, I do not want Method1,2,3 to call Action().

Comment: I personally prefer using Rx.Net's RefCountDisposible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As SLaks has pointed out, a ReadWriterLock was a great solution.

Here is what I ended up implementing:

```
private static ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
private static Session _session = new Session();

public static void Method1() {
    _lock.EnterReadLock();
    try {
        if(_session != null)
            _session.Action();
    }
    finally
    {
        _lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
public static void Method2() {
    _lock.EnterReadLock();
    try {
        if(_session != null)
            _session.Action();
    }
    finally
    {
        _lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
public static void Method3() {
    _lock.EnterReadLock();
    try {
        if(_session != null)
            _session.Action();
    }
    finally
    {
        _lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
public static void Method4(string path) {
    _lock.EnterWriteLock();
    try {
        if(_session != null)
            _session.Action();
    }
    finally
    {
        _lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

Great performance, no threading issues!

Answer (score 0):

```
private static RefCountDisposable _refCountDisposible = new RefCountDisposable();
private static Session _session = new Session();

public Constructor()
{
    _refCountDisposible = new RefCountDisposable(
           Disposible.Create(() => _session.Disconnect()));
}

public static void Method1() {
    using(_refCountDisposible.GetDisposible())
        if(_session != null)
            _session.Action();

}
public static void Method2() {
    using(_refCountDisposible.GetDisposible())

        if(_session != null)
            _session.Action();
}
public static void Method3() {
    using(_refCountDisposible.GetDisposible())
        if(_session != null)
            _session.Action();
}
public static void Method4(string path) {
    _refCountDisposible.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

How about ManualResetEvent?

```
M4()
{
  _event.Reset();
  try
    //reconnect
  finally
    _event.Set();
}

M1,2,3()
{
  _event.WaitOne();
  //do actions
}
```

Comment: Suppose M4 is not called for 1 hour.

Comment: @L.B, _event can starts with signaled state.

Comment: Then what about *second call of M1,2,3*. `Sequence: M1(), M2(),`

Comment: @L.B, I am not sure if I understand your concern. For ManualResetEvent  WaitOne will return immediately if the event is signaled without resetting it.

Comment: Suppose M4() is never called, `_event` will never be signaled. So entering a method(1,2 or 3) second time is not possible.

Comment: @L.B, you can do _event = new ManualResetEvent(true) in the static initializer. But I am feeling there might be an InitialConnect method since the purpose seems to be to hold connection-related calls during reconnecting. So the event can be set to signaled during the initial connecting. The idea is, _event is non-signaled whenever there is no connection and signaled when connection is ready.

Comment: Sorry, I can't resolve the communication error between us. Forget it. Just try to understand why this code wouldn't work. Or better write a real  code and invoke `M1(), M1(), M1()`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46785/discussion-between-kai-wang-and-l-b)